# No Vertical Spacing in Multicols

Tags: spacing, multicolumn

I just started using LaTeX this week. So currently, I am making exam-type files. I use the `\itemsep=\fill` option to make sure that there is a vertical space in between each `\item`. However, when I use the `multicol` package, the `\itemsep=\fill` does not work anymore.

Here is the document. Notice that numbers 1 and 2(a) and (b) are spaced in the way I wanted, while 3(a) - 3(d) are not.
[image: Resulting Document]

Here is the code of my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate} \itemsep=\fill

  \item Find all possible values of $x$ in $x^6 - 64 = 0$.

  \item Simplify each.
    \begin{enumerate} \itemsep=\fill
      \item $\dfrac{6b^6 + 4b^4 + 8b^2}{2b^2}$
      \item $\dfrac{2x^3 + 9x^2 - 11x + 3}{2x-1}$ 
      \item $\dfrac{48a^2b^4 + 32ab^5 - 8b^6 + 4ab^2}{-8a^2b^3}$ 
      \item $\dfrac{8c^3+5c^2+2c^4-4c-4}{c^2+4c+3}$
      \vfill
     \end{enumerate}

   \item Perform the indicated operations then simplify.
     \begin{multicols}{2}
     \begin{enumerate} \itemsep=\fill
       \item $(x+1)(x-1)$
       \item $(5x+2)(6x-3)$
       \item $(6x-10)(3x+8)$
       \item $(2x+1)(x-3)$
       \vfill
     \end{enumerate}
     \end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Do you have suggestion(s) and/or solution(s) for this? It will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: why not a fixed length such as 1cm?

Comment: \vfill doesn't work in a minipage either, since the vertical size isn't fixed.  Use [twocolumn] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a variable lengths such as `\fill` and `\vfill`, I'd use a fixed length, say, `2.5cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate} \itemsep=2.5cm

  \item Find all possible values of $x$ in $x^6 - 64 = 0$.

  \item Simplify each.
    \begin{enumerate} \itemsep=2.5cm
      \item $\dfrac{6b^6 + 4b^4 + 8b^2}{2b^2}$
      \item $\dfrac{2x^3 + 9x^2 - 11x + 3}{2x-1}$ 
      \item $\dfrac{48a^2b^4 + 32ab^5 - 8b^6 + 4ab^2}{-8a^2b^3}$ 
      \item $\dfrac{8c^3+5c^2+2c^4-4c-4}{c^2+4c+3}$
      %\vfill
     \end{enumerate}

   \item Perform the indicated operations then simplify.
     \begin{multicols}{2}
     \begin{enumerate} \itemsep=2.5cm
       \item $(x+1)(x-1)$
       \item $(5x+2)(6x-3)$
       \item $(6x-10)(3x+8)$
       \item $(2x+1)(x-3)$
       %\vfill
     \end{enumerate}
     \end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason why I used `\itemsep=\fill` is that I wanted to make sure that there will be equal spaces per item. How will I determine the fixed length without too much trial and error? (i.e. What made you say that `2.5 cm` is the ideal fixed length in this case?)

Comment: @JohnSmith - I didn't claim that `2.5cm` was *ideal*. I just eyeballed the page, guessed that `2.5cm` might be "about right", and gave it a try. For sure, I didn't try `2.25cm`, `2.75cm`, etc. I don't think there's much of a point in seeking perfection in this matter, is there?